# Can I apply multithreading for computationally intensive task in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, cpython, gil

**Update:** To save your time, I give the answer directly here. Python **can not** utilize multi cpu cores at the same time if the you use pure Python to write your code. But Python **can** utilize multi cores at the same time when it calls some functions or packages which are written in C, like Numpy, etc.

---

I have heard that "**multithreading in python is not the real multithreading, because of GIL**". And I also heard that "**python multithreading is okay to handle IO intensive task instead of computationally intensive task, because there is only one threading running at the same time**".

But my experience made me rethink this question. My experience shows that even for computationally intensive task, python multithreading **can** accelerate the computation nearly learly. (Befor multithreading, it cost me 300 seconds to run the following program, after I use multithreading, it cost me 100 seconds.)

The following figures shows that 5 threads were created by `python` with `CPython` as the compiler with package `threading` and all the `cpu cores` are nearly 100% percentage.

I think the screenshots can prove that the 5 cpu cores are running at the same time.

So can anyone give me the explanation? Can I apply multithreading for computationally intensive task in python?  Or can multi threads/cores run at the same time in python?

My code:

```
import threading
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate


number_list = list(range(10))

def image_interpolation():
    while True:
        number = None
        with threading.Lock():
            if len(number_list):
                number = number_list.pop()
        if number is not None:
            # Make a fake image - you can use yours.
            image = np.ones((20000, 20000))
            # Make your orig array (skipping the extra dimensions).
            orig = np.random.rand(12800, 16000)
            # Make its coordinates; x is horizontal.
            x = np.linspace(0, image.shape[1], orig.shape[1])
            y = np.linspace(0, image.shape[0], orig.shape[0])
            # Make the interpolator function.
            f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, orig, kind='linear')

        else:
            return 1

workers=5
thd_list = []
t1 = time.time()

for i in range(workers):
    thd = threading.Thread(target=image_interpolation)
    thd.start()
    thd_list.append(thd)

for thd in thd_list:
    thd.join()

t2 = time.time()
print("total time cost with multithreading: " + str(t2-t1))
number_list = list(range(10))

for i in range(10):
    image_interpolation()

t3 = time.time()

print("total time cost without multithreading: " + str(t3-t2))
```

output is:

```
total time cost with multithreading: 112.71922039985657
total time cost without multithreading: 328.45561170578003
```

screenshot of `top` **during** multithreading
[image: top]

screenshot of `top -H` **during** multithreading
[image: top -H]

screenshot of `top` then press `1`. **during** multithreading
[image: top press 1]

screenshot of `top -H` **without** multithreading
[image: top]

Comment: What code did you test it with?

Comment: If they all have different PIDs then you are probably using multiprocessing by accident.

Comment: @FiddleStix Ya, I was wondering about that. Also, `509 total, 508 sleeping` suggests that no actual work is being done.

Comment: @FiddleStix I use threading package in python, so I think I did not use multiprocessing.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think the `509 total, 508 sleeping` does not give any information about the runing thread  number. It means task number or process nunber.

Comment: @JingnanJia As `FiddleStix` notes though, you *appear* to be using multiprocessing since you have many separate python processes in your screenshot. Again, the code that was used to test this would be very helpful.

Comment: @FiddleStix I think the different PIDs is just because I used "top -H" to show each thread.

Comment: I updated the detailed code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, Python has a "global interpreter lock" (GIL) that prevents two threads of *Python code* running at the same time.  The reason that multi-threading can speed up IO bound tasks is that Python releases the GIL when, for example, listening on a network socket or waiting for a disk read.  So the GIL does not prevent two lots of work being done simultaneously by your computer, it prevents two Python threads in the same Python process being run simultaneously.

In your example, you use numpy and scipy. These are largely written in C and utilise libraries (BLAS, LAPACK, etc) written in C/Fortran/Assembly.  When you perform operations on numpy arrays, it is akin to listening on socket in that [the GIL is released](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ParallelProgramming.html).  When the GIL is released and the numpy array operations called, numpy gets to decide how to perform the work.  If it wants, it can spawn other threads or processes and the BLAS subroutines it calls might spawn other threads.  Precisely if/how this is done can be configured at build time if you want to compile numpy from source.

So, to summarise, you've have found an exception to the rule.  If you were to repeat the experiment using only pure Python functions, you would get quite different results (e.g. see the "Comparison" section of the page linked to above).

Comment: Do you mean, if I use functions from packages which may be written in C, then multi threads are able run at the same time. But if I use functions built by only pure python, then multi threads can not run at the same time. Right?

Comment: Yes, precisely.  I'm not sure whether the Python interpreter releases the GIL automatically or whether the C code (i.e. numpy in this case) has to do so explicitly.  In other words, I'm not certain that it applies to all C code called from Python, it probably depends on the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Python threading is a real threading, just that no two threads at once can be in the interpreter (and this is what GIL is about). The native part of the code can well run in parallel without contention on multiple threads, only when diving back into the interpreter they'll have to serialize among each other.

The fact that you have all CPU cores loaded to 100% alone is not a proof that you are using the machine "efficiently". You need to make sure that the CPU usage is not due to the context switching.

If you switch to multiprocessing instead of threading (they are very similar), you won't have to double guess, but then you'll have to marshal the payload when passing between threads.

So need to measure everything anyway.