# Sage Maker Studio CPU Usage

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm working in sage maker studio, and I have a single instance running one computationally intensive task:

[image]

It appears that the kernel running my task is maxed out, but the actual instance is only using a small amount of its resources. Is there some sort of throttling occurring? Can I configure this so that more of the instance is utilized?

Comment: Where can I find CPU and Memory Usage in the Studio UI?

Comment: See some of the answers below. you can click the little "Instance MEM" slider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ml.c5.xlarge instance comes with 4 vCPU. However, Python only uses a single CPU by default. (Source: [Can I apply multithreading for computationally intensive task in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121703/can-i-apply-multithreading-for-computationally-intensive-task-in-python))

As a result, the overall CPU utilization of your ml.c5.xlarge instance is low. To utilize all the vCPUs, you can try multiprocessing.

The examples below are performed using a 2 vCPU + 4 GiB instance.

In the first picture, multiprocessing is not set up. The instance CPU utilization peaks at around 50%.

single processing:
[image: single processing]

In the second picture, I created 50 processes to be run simultaneously. The instance CPU utilization rises to 100% immediately.

multiprocessing:
[image: multiprocessing]

Comment: That's interesting. So the percentage for the kernel is the master process, and the instance percentage is a percentage of actual CPU usage for the whole system? It'd be cool if that were more explicit, but when you think about it that's actually pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It might be something off with these stats your seeing, or they are showing different time spans, or the kernel has a certain resources assignment out of the total instance.

I suggest opening a terminal and running `top` to see what's actually going on and which UI stat it matches (note your opening the instance's terminal, and not the Jupyter UI instance terminal).

Comment: Can I open the instance terminal through sagemaker studio?

Comment: Yes. Via the $_ button at the top line of the notebook you have open. 
Not via File->New->Terminal, which opens the terminal on the Jupyter UI instance.

Comment: It seems like the Data Science kernel doesn't have `top` installed. You can get a terminal from the `$_` button, but it's extremely limited in what's installed. I need to check whether it even has `ps` - I think it didn't (because that would be my one-shot fallback) but I'm not sufficiently sure to make it a definitive statement on SO!